# How can we solve this integral $\frac{x\,dx}{x^2-x-6}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1\frac{x\, dx}{x^2-x-6} = [uv]^1_0 -\int_0^1 v\,du = ?$$

$u=x,du=dx,dv=\frac{dx}{x^2-x-6},v=?$ (this is my problem.)

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Please format your questions with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Write $x^2-x-6$ as $(x-3)(x+2)$ and use partial fractions: $$\frac 1{x^2-x-6}=\frac A{x-3}+\frac B{x+2}$$ where $A,B$ are constants. Then multiply this by $x$ so that the integral can be easily solved using $\ln$.

Comment: Ok. I am on it.

Comment: Didn't the OP want $\int \frac{x}{x^2-x-6}~\mathrm dx$?

Comment: Yes. I said in the post that after finding $A$ and $B$, multiply by $x$ to get something of the form $\dfrac x{x-a}=1+\dfrac a{x-a}$ which can be easily integrated.

Comment: I got 1/5 ln(x-3)-1/5ln(x+2).ok?

Comment: v= to what now?

Comment: No need to use substitution. Integrate directly!

Answer (score 0):

Find constants $A,\,B$ such that $\frac{x}{x^2-x-6}=\frac{A}{x-3}+\frac{B}{x+2}$. I get $A=\frac{3}{5},\,B=\frac{2}{5}$.